# How to process the raw response generated by the WSDL2Apex Callout?

Tags: apex, integration, callout, soap, wsdl2apex

I am getting a huge chunk of raw response from the WSDL2Apex web service call out and I want it to be able to be processed into APEX Data structures, i.e. lists and maps.

**Raw Response Snippet:**

> PartrtnerUserKey_type_info=(PartnerUserKey,
>   http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI, null, 0, 1, false),
>   UserID=null, UserID_type_info=(UserID,
>   http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI, null, 0, 1, false),
>   apex_schema_type_info=(http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI, true,
>   false), field_order_type_info=(ClientID, ID, PartnerClientKey, UserID,
>   PartnerUserKey, CreatedBy, ModifiedBy, EnterpriseID, CustomerKey,
>   CustomerID)], Client_type_info=(Client,
>   http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI, null, 0, 1, false),
>   CorrelationID=null, CorrelationID_type_info=(CorrelationID,
>   http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI, null, 0, 1, false),
>   CreatedDate=null, CreatedDate_type_info=(CreatedDate,
>   http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI, null, 0, 1, false),
>   CustomerKey=null, CustomerKey_type_info=(CustomerKey,
>   http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI, null, 0, 1, false),
>   EmailAddress=…, EmailAddress_type_info=(EmailAddress,
>   http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI, null, 0, 1, false), ID=null,
>   ID_type_info=(ID, http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI, null, 0, 1,
>   false), ModifiedDate=null, ModifiedDate_type_info=(ModifiedDate,
>   http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI, null, 0, 1, true),
>   ObjectID=null, ObjectID_type_info=(ObjectID,
>   http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI, null, 0, 1, true),
>   ObjectState=null, ObjectState_type_info=(ObjectState,
>   http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI, null, 0, 1, false),
>   Owner=null, Owner_type_info=(Owner,
>   http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI, null, 0, 1, false),
>   PartnerKey=null, PartnerKey_type_info=(PartnerKey,
>   http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI, null, 0, 1, true),
>   PartnerProperties=(MainProperty:[Name=Createddate,
>   Name_type_info=(Name, http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI, null, 1,
>   1, false), Value=4/12/2016 6:07:00 AM, Value_type_info=(Value,
>   http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI, null, 1, 1, false),
>   apex_schema_type_info=(http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI, true,
>   false), field_order_type_info=(Name, Value)]),
>   PartnerProperties_type_info=(PartnerProperties,
>   http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI, null, 0, -1, false),
>   Status=Active, Status_type_info=(Status,
>   http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI, null, 0, 1, false),
>   SubscriberKey=Matt3, SubscriberKey_type_info=(SubscriberKey,
>   http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI, null, 0, 1, false), Type=null,
>   Type_type_info=(Type, http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI, null, 0,
>   1, true),
>   apex_schema_type_info=(http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI, true,
>   false), field_order_type_info=(EmailAddress, Status, SubscriberKey,
>   Client, PartnerKey, PartnerProperties, CreatedDate, ModifiedDate, ID,
>   ObjectID, ...)], ...), Results_type_info=(Results,
>   http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI, null, 0, -1, false),
>   apex_schema_type_info=(http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI, true,
>   false), field_order_type_info=(OverallStatus, RequestID, Results)]

---

How to convert/parse it into Apex Data structures?

Answer (score 0):

Wsdl2Apex should be handling this conversion for you. Typically the only way to get the raw response that you have is to do a `System.debug(calloutResponse);` on the web service response objects. E.g. If the debug output includes members with the `_type_info` suffix then you are dealing with the WSDL2Apex generated stub classes.